# Get coordinates (row,column) of a table in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to get (row,column) coordinates of a table?

Example:

```
tbl1:                              tbl2:
+--------+--------+--------+       +------+-----------+---------+
| Name   |   ROW  |   COL  |       |  ROW |  COL_0    |  COL_1  |
+--------+--------+--------+       +------+-----------+---------+
| VALUE1 |     0  |     0  |       |    0 |  OPEN     |  CLOSE  |
| VALUE2 |     2  |     1  |       |    1 |  RIGHT    |  LEFT   |
| VALUE3 |     1  |     0  |       |    2 |  OFFLINE  |  ONLINE |
+--------+--------+--------+       +------+-----------+---------+
```

The result should look like:

```
+--------+----------+     
| Name   |   ROWCOL | 
+--------+----------+ 
| VALUE1 |   OPEN   | 
| VALUE2 |   ONLINE | 
| VALUE3 |   RIGHT  | 
+--------+----------+
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it's better you explain us what you want to achieve, this sounds pretty odd.

Comment: I just want to construct a MySQL query that using tbl1 and tbl2 as inputs gives the third table as a result.

Comment: Are you sure this is how you want to structure your database?

Comment: I did not want to add extra information since I thought it would be confusing, thats why I preferred to keep it simple and just write to simple tables and a result to show what Im intending to do.

Comment: Abe: No, Im not sure. Im pretty new to MySQL. However Im sure that tbl2 will not grow having more columns in the future.

Comment: I think we need to see WHY you want to do this.  Please edit your post and add an explanation of the real-world situation that requires this approach.

Comment: You should also remember that the order of rows in a table in SQL (any SQL database) is undefined except in the context of an `order by` clause in a specific query.

Comment: To add to @Jim's suggestion, if you can describe the data you are trying to store then we can probably suggest a better structure for your data.  This will make your life going forward MUCH easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an odd requirement but I believe this will work:

```
SELECT name, 
CASE COL
  WHEN 0 THEN COL_0
  WHEN 1 THEN Col_1
END as rowcol
FROM tbl1 as t1
INNER JOIN tbl2 as t2
ON t1.ROW = t2.ROW
```

Comment: Thank you Abe! This is exactly what I was looking for. It worked as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think relying on implicit data like rownumbers or so are not a good idea.

I propose to reorganize tbl2 to something like this:

```
create table tbl2 (
   rowid integer,
   colid integer,
   textvalue varchar(32)
);
```

Data will look like

```
0 0 OPEN
0 1 CLOSE
1 0 RIGHT
1 1 LEFT
...
```

which allows you to obtain your result with

```
select tbl1.name as Name, tbl2.textvaluevalue as ROWCOL
from tbl1, tbl2
where tbl1.ROW = tbl2.rowid and tbl1.COL = tbl2.colid
```